# Extracting the 'end' of a string, conditions or regular expression?

Tags: regex

I have a data table - can be extracted to text or spreadsheet - The column has random text with areas in square metres that I want to copy to a new column in hectares. (So parse text and divide by 10,000).
e.g.

```
Deposited Plan 172499, 53,310 m2
Deposited Plan 166167, 853 m2
This plan has no area stated
Section 21 Block I Wellington District, 403,573 m2
```

Output column should have:

```
 5.3310
 0.0853

40.3573
```

Is there a way I can automate this in LibreOffice Calc, or with a regular expression editor like TextCrawler? Or perhaps using an AutoIt script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Try with this

```
/([0-9]+,*[0-9]+\sm2)$/
```

Comment: Thanks Yves.

Got it working in LibreOffice Calc with the following expression:

=MID(A1,(SEARCH("([0-9]+,*[0-9]+\sm2)$",A1)),249)